Android app that reminds GPS position when a Bluetooth device goes out-of-range
I am looking for a simple Android app for my phone (an Android 13 phone)  that can remind GPS position when a Bluetooth device goes out-of-range.
Basically I need to replace a paid service (now expired) that provides info on where I parked the car.
I have found a few apps that seemed promising, but I got suspicious when I start noticing that none of them was hosted in the official Play Store.
Given that it would be enough for me that the app could check every few (5? 10? 20?) seconds if a specific Bluetooth device is in range, and keep track of the latest GPS position(s) when it was detected (optionally allowing me to copy that GPS position and opening in google maps), it seems reasonable that such a basic service would be free.
As an alternative, if a similar app does not exist, I could consider trying to write the app myself (I heard that, with kiwi, the real python code, without the boilerplate, would easily be less than 200 lines) but my developer skills are far from being exceptional.

You don't need to code anything, you can always use Tasker, which is normally used to quickly solve specific problems that don't have good app coverage or should be more catered toward specific user needs.
It has BT Near state that you can use to check if a device is in range. It allows you to change frequency of checks. Then you can use Get Location action for GPS coordinate and e.g. append it to a file with Write File action.
